# Unable to access this after making HTTP request inside MobX action

Tags: reactjs, mobx, mobx-react

I have a MobX action called doLogin(). It is able to access `this.` before making an HTTP request, but as soon as the HTTP request is made this becomes `undefined`. I've been at this trying different iterations of arrow functions, bindings etc for about 4 hours now and starting to lose my mind.

I have tried using different HTTP request libraries (`axios`, `request`) as well as the Fetch API. All yield the same result.

I have tried using the MobX `runInAction()` utility even though I don't have strict mode enabled. Same result.

AuthStore.js

```
import { observable, action } from "mobx";
import axios from "axios";

class AuthStore {
  @observable token = "";
  @observable isLoggedIn = false;
  @observable loading = false;
  @observable error = null;

  @action setToken = (token) => {
    this.token = token;
    this.isLoggedIn = true;
    this.loading = false;
  }

  @action doLogin = (email, password) => {
    this.loading = true; // works as expected
    console.log("this before: ", this); // prints AuthStore

    axios.post('http://my-api.com/users/authenticate', {
      email: email,
      password: password
    })
    .then(function (response) {
      console.log("this after: ", this); // prints undefined
      this.setToken(response.data.response.token); // err
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log("Auth store error ", error);
    });
  }
}

const store = new AuthStore();
export default store;
```

Login.js

```
import React from "react";
import { Form, Input, Button, Checkbox } from 'antd';
import { inject, observer } from 'mobx-react';

import "./Login.less";


@inject('AuthStore')
@observer
export default class Login extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    // To disabled submit button at the beginning.
    this.props.form.validateFields();
  }

  handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.form.validateFields((err, values) => {
      if (!err) {
        this.props.AuthStore.doLogin(values.email, values.password);
      }
    });
  }

  hasErrors = (fieldsError) => {
    return Object.keys(fieldsError).some(field => fieldsError[field]);
  }

  render() {
    const { loading } = this.props.AuthStore;

    const { getFieldDecorator, getFieldsError, getFieldError, isFieldTouched } = this.props.form;

    const emailError = isFieldTouched('email') && getFieldError('email');
    const passwordError = isFieldTouched('password') && getFieldError('password');

    return (
      <div id="login">

        <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} className="login-form">

          <Form.Item validateStatus={emailError ? 'error' : ''} help={emailError || ''}>
            {getFieldDecorator('email', {
              rules: [{ required: true, message: 'Please input your email!' }],
            })(
              <Input prefix={<i className="far fa-user"></i>} placeholder="Username" />
            )}
          </Form.Item>
          <Form.Item validateStatus={passwordError ? 'error' : ''} help={passwordError || ''}>
            {getFieldDecorator('password', {
              rules: [{ required: true, message: 'Please input your Password!' }],
            })(
              <Input prefix={<i className="far fa-lock"></i>} type="password" placeholder="Password" />
            )}
          </Form.Item>
          <Form.Item>
            {getFieldDecorator('remember', {
              valuePropName: 'checked',
              initialValue: true,
            })(
              <Checkbox>Remember me</Checkbox>
            )}
            <a className="login-form-forgot" href="">Forgot password</a>
            <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit" className="login-form-button" loading={loading} disabled={this.hasErrors(getFieldsError())}>
              Log in
            </Button>
            Don't have an account? <a href="">Register now!</a>
          </Form.Item>
        </Form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

Login = Form.create({})(Login);
```

I expect to be able to call this.setToken(response.data.response.token) in my action after I get a response from the API, but I am unable to.

edit:

I fixed it using `$this=this`. Not sure if it's the correct way to handle the problem, but this is just a personal project and after already wasting hours on this one function I'm over it.

So now it looks like

```
@action doLogin = (email, password) => {
    const $this = this
    this.loading = true; // works as expected

    axios.post('http://my-api.com/users/authenticate', {
      email: email,
      password: password
    })
    .then(function (response) {
      $this.setToken(response.data.response.token);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log("Auth store error ", error);
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are running into is unrelated to any of the libraries mentioned in the post. You should investigate how `this` and `function` interact with each other in JavaScript.

This is a great place to start: https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/tree/master/scope%20%26%20closures. After going trough that, it will take you 10 seconds to spot the error, without understanding how either MobX or axios work (the problem is unrelated to these libs). That might sound blunt, but taking 2 hours now to grok this essential JS concept, will save you many times 4 hours in the future.